# Foreach different with first array in php

Tags: php, foreach

This is what I tried

```
$a = array("a", "b", "c");
$b = $a[0];

if (array_search($b,$a) == 0) {
    echo $a[0]." and some code";
}
else {
    foreach($a as $c) {
        echo $c."and some different code";
    }
}
```

And I want the outcome to be

```
a and some code
b and some different code
c and some different code etc...
```

Comment: what is your goal? please give more examples because in this case the best solution is just type `echo` three times

Comment: Perhaps try and put into words what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic of finding the first item seems a bit redundant, also as the `foreach()` is only done if it doesn't find the first item (which it always will).

To simplify the code, just echo out the first item, use `array_shift()` to remove this value and `foreach()` over the rest of the array...

```
$a=array("a","b","c");

echo $a[0]." and some code".PHP_EOL;
array_shift($a);
foreach($a as $c){
    echo $c." and some different code".PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: I think array changing can be little confusing so maybe `array_slice` will be better solution in this case

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko if you want to add your own answer then please do so.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a foreach with the index defined and use a case / if statements?

```php
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if($key==0){
     echo $value . "and some code";
    } else if ($key===1){
     echo $value . "and some different code";
    } else {
      echo $value . "and some even more different code";
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move foreach one level up and you do not need to search if you explicitly specify value. Plus some other minor fixes. This is the solution closest to your code:

```
$a = array("a","b","c");
$b = $a[0];

foreach($a as $c) {
    if ($b == $c) {
        echo $b . " and some code\n";
    } else {
        echo $c . " and some different code\n";
    }
}
```